# getenv not working in EC2 Server

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to deploy to production my app that is working well in local.

Thing is when try:

```
dd(getenv('APP_ENV'));
```

it returns "false"

but when I connect ssh and type:

```
php artisan env
```

I get

```
production
```

Any idea why it stopped working???

For the record, In production, my deploy script execute 3 commands:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache
```

I mention it because it is possibly the only software config that is different.

EDIT: I identify that the problematic command is:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

If if do:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

problem is solved.

Tx!

Comment: Where exactly is that `dd` code executed from?

Comment: in my footer. Updated question. problem is php artisan config:cache. But still don't know what's going on

Comment: Did you try omitting config:cache from your deploy scripts?

Comment: yep, when omitting it works. But I need to maintain it because it is much faster

Comment: I am going to assuming you are using homestead? If yes, then my next question would be is your EC2 fresh install? if yes, then please check your nginx configuration and make sure that APP_ENV has been defined perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I use homestead in local, and in prod, I use forge. So, I don't really know where the env var are defined :( as I use Forge UI

Comment: Just wanted to add, that the EDIT was correct. I was executing both commands and nothing happened. If I do only `php artisan config:clear` then the problem is fixed. So for further references - **never execute both, try one and check first!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using a cached config the `.env` file is not used anymore so `getenv` is useless, because the config is loaded from:

```
bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

Instead you can get the current environment from the loaded application configuration like so:

```php
config('app.env');
```

Or directly using the `app` helper function:

```php
app('env');
```

As a third option you can always use the `environment` method to get the current environment:

```php
app()->environment(); // or App::environment()
```

---

Laravel uses the [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) library internally to load the configuration keys from the .env file and [add them to the environment variables](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/blob/master/src/Loader.php#L338) using [putenv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php), but when you cache your configuration that loading part is not done anymore because Laravel detects that there is a cache file present and uses that instead, so those keys from `.env` are not loaded into the environment, this not accessible via `getenv`.

And because configuration values from the `.env` file are only cached when they are used in an actual configuration file from the `config` directory, you need to create a configuration option for them to be cached and accessible when you're using the cache.

So if you want to have a `BASE_URL` key in your `.env` file with this value:

```
BASE_URL=http://domain.com/
```

If you want to be able to access its value when the configuration is cached, you need to use it in a configuration file. For example, you can add it to your `config/app.php` file like so:

```php
'base_url' => env('BASE_URL')
```

Then you can access even when the configuration iit using:

```php
config('app.base_url')
```

---

You can read more about accessing configuration values in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#accessing-configuration-values).

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.

Comment: what is not clear to me, is how to retrieve env vars when cached. I can make differents cases for dev or prod, but I see now where how to retrieve my cached env var

Comment: Laravel uses the [dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) library internally to load the configuration keys from the `.env` file and [add them to the environment variables](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/blob/master/src/Loader.php#L338) using [`putenv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php), but when you cache your configuration that loading part is not done anymore because Laravel detects that there is a cache file and uses that, so those keys from `.env` are not loaded into the environment. Other environment vars set from any other places are still accessible via `getenv`.

Comment: However when you first ran `artisan config:cache` the command took the values from `.env` and  stored them in the config cache file I mentioned, so using `app('env')` is just the same as `getenv('APP_ENV')` as far as your Laravel configuration goes. I suggest using `app('env')` all the time instead of `getenv`, because it will work both if you have or haven't cached your configuration settings.

Comment: ok, I get it, but how should I retrieve APP_NAME for ex? app('name'). if I have a var called URL_BASE, how should I retrieve it???

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the clarifications from the previous comments as well as a solution to your latest question.

Comment: tx for help @Bogdan. Now I understand better. But when I try it in test, it doesn't work.. Is it normal ? As I understand, it should work in all env, shouldn't it?

Comment: ok, In production, I got it working, but not in local. So, each time I will need to invoke env variable, I should check the environment? Isn't it kind of heavy???

Comment: This isn't great if you're using a library that uses GETENV (like Google's)... I guess there must be another way